# Labeling layers with Python in QGIS. LinePlacementFlags

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, labeling

How could I set `LinePlacementFlags` with Python in QGIS?
My code is something like:

```
palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
palyr.readFromLayer(layer)
palyr.enabled = True
palyr.fieldName = "attribute"
```

Then I've tried:

```
palyr.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
```

And my labels are on the line. I want them above the line, but I can't figure how to do this.
I found there is [LinePlacementFlags](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#aac410504b5f2c1d09929c2beef56d26e) type. But

```
palyr.LinePlacementFlags= QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [placementFlags](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#abeb4d081fd4eb7debb30dfcdd5be8d58). So,

```
palyr.placementFlags = QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine
```

should work. Note that LinePlacementFlags can be combined, so

```
palyr.placementFlags = QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine | QgsPalLayerSettings.BelowLine
```

will allow labels above and below the line, but not on over the line.